# What is the definition of unsigned() function in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I am unable to find the function signature of unsigned() function in vhdl. what types does it accept as an argument?

Comment: It is just a type cast (not a function per se).  Will only work if it operates over an array with the same base type, i.e. std_logic.

Comment: See http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/typeconv.html

Answer (score 2):

A type conversion isn't a function, it's a basic operation. You don't get to peer into the innards of basic operations. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5. Types, 5.1 General, paragraph 3.

There are implicit type conversions, such as between *universal integer* and integer. That you're asking says you're interested in an explicit type conversion.

9.3.6 Type conversions

> A type conversion provides for explicit conversion between closely related types.
>   ...
>   Explicit type conversions are allowed between *closely related types*. In particular, a type is closely related to itself. Other types are closely related only under the following conditions:
>
> - *Abstract numeric types*—Any abstract numeric type is closely related to any other abstract numeric type.
>    - *Array types*—Two array types are closely related if and only if the types have the same dimensionality and the element types are closely related
>
> No other types are closely related.

Not to be confused with a conversion function.